# Web application authentication design pattern

Tags: database, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

I'm working on a web application and I'm having problem accessing the database on server side because there is no user for the DB proxy to map. In other word, I have a method which will start as soon as the application comes online and will call itself every 5 seconds to check for new messages. If it receives a specified message, it then goes to the database and finds whatever it needs. However, accessing database on server side wouldn't be possible because there is no user for the DB proxy to map. So what is a good design pattern for this type of application? Should I need an application account for these type of automation process?

Btw, I'm using Weblogic JPA 2.1 for database stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, what exactly do you mean by "*no user for the DB proxy to map*"?

I assume, you meant that you don't have a user known by a session who connects to the database?

If yes, you usually wouldn't do that anyway and instead nearly always have a database user for your application. Then, no matter a user triggers a database call by an action or the backend triggers it by some scheduling, it will always be the same user who does it. In your Java EE application, you'd have a datasource containing this user in its configuration and all your application parts use the related entity manager when doing persistent actions or queries.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Because of my backend stuff is session-less so there is no known user to connect to the database.  I was thinking the same by creating a separate account only to serve backend database access. Looks like i'm on the right track. Thank you for your help.